# How does kinesthetic work and with what do we sense this?

Tags: senses

I know that kinesthetic and proprioception are different things but, in contrast to proprioception, I don't know how kinesthetic works.

A broad explaination as well as very specific(but explained for 17 year olds) would be nice.